# Outlet attached to dimmer doesn't turn off completely

Tags: electrical, lighting

I live in an apartment built in the late 80s that has an outlet in the dining area located at the top of the wall.  It is attached to a dimmer. The top socket turns off and on and dims with the dimmer control.  The bottom socket is on and lights and dims but does not turn off!  I recently bought a swag lamp with a 60 watt max rating.  To get more light, can I use a dimmable 100 watt equivalent LED bulb in the top socket?

I’ve read all that I can to try to understand the leading edge/trailing edge, old dimmers, new dimmers, use this not that but you can use that but not in this.  All my reading has led to nothing but confusion. Moving is not an option. Changing the dimmer is not an option.  Please advise.

Comment: Where are you on this planet?  If this is in the US, the current situation violates NEC 404.14(E), full stop.

Comment: "lamp with a 60 watt max rating. To get more light, can I use a dimmable 100 watt equivalent LED bulb?" yes, you can put a [14 watt] light bulb in a fixture rated for 60w. - bad enough you have a receptacle on a dimmer, but "The bottom socket is on and lights and dims but does not turn off!" .... uh? That's when you call your landlord and ask, WTF is all this then?

Comment: If you exchange which plugs the lamps are in, does the problem stay with the lamp, or move to the other socket?  The most likely explanation here is that the sockets are wired exactly the same, but the fixture that refuses to turn off has an LED bulb.  Refusing to go all the way off is normal LED weirdness.

Comment: I'd simply replace the dimmer switch with a normal one, whoever put an outlet on a dimmer is an idiot.  Different bulb types require different types of dimmers and if its from the 80s I doubt it's designed to properly handle LEDs appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a dimmer on a standard receptacle. [Here's why](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1BDeOHR951g).

So it's a code violation as it sits. If you're renting, then you are correct that you can't do work *without landlord permission*; however talk to the permit issuing authority in your town. While 99% of electrical work must be done by a licensed electrician in a rental unit, almost all *do permit* "trivial" work such as changing a light switch, receptacle or light fixture to be done by landlord, tenant or unlicensed handyman.  Those few which require an electrician *for a light switch* also are serious about the landlord correcting code violations.

However if you are fixed on keeping the dimmer *for other reasons*, then your only remaining option is to replace the receptacle with the [Lutron receptacle mentioned in that video](https://www.lutron.com/TechnicalDocumentLibrary/048109c.pdf).  Since you're only using it for lighting anyway, that shouldn't be an inconvenience.

This is the SCR-15-HDTR. *Wow, it is hard to find*, and [prices vary dramatically by color](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B006XY2L2W).

You need to change the plugs on your lamps to the special Lutron RP-FDU plug.  What's very cool is the plug is compatible with normal sockets.  So you'll still be able to use the lamp forever in a normal socket.

The special socket simply rejects things which are not lamps.  Slick!

Honestly, if it were me, I'd change the switch to a plain switch and then use a [plug-in dimmer](https://www.homedepot.com/b/Electrical-Wiring-Devices-Light-Controls-Dimmers/Plug-In/N-5yc1vZc34iZ1z17md8).

If everything is "not an option", then I hope keeping your smoke detectors tip-top isn't "not an option" either.

Comment: It's an apartment. Therefore, the tenant can't change any of it.

Comment: Yeah, can't "refuse" to make changes in a rental. It's just not an option. Contacting the landlord certainly is.

Comment: @ecnerwal If the landlord permits, You can change receptacles and switches most everywhere. Most AHJs allow "trivial" work to be done by landlord, tenant or handyman - switches, receptacles, lamps.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the landlord and telling him/her that the bottom socket is connected to a dimmer and that you could have destroyed your computer with it. They'll probably fix it. When they are fixing it they may give it a new dimmer, or if it is open anyway you can find out if the dimmer is suitable for led lights. This must be a strange dimmer. If the bottom socket dims but does not go off, then the dimmer must have two exits, one that dims and turns off, and one that only dims. Never heard of anything like that and I have no idea what it could be used for.

The led lights you buy for this lamp need to have 'dimmable' written on the box explicitly.

The top socket can be removed and replaced by a cover plate with a cable hole. The lamp can then be connected to the wiring directly.

Comment: I agree with calling the landlord, but I don't think dimmers should be connected to _sockets/outlets_ only to lighting fixtures.

Comment: @FreeMan: I completely agree, but I wouldn't give my landlord a hard time over a socket that is mounted next to the ceiling. I'll never accidentally plug my laptop in that one.